# Creating a temp table in mysql for querying when the main table is getting updated

Tags: mysql

i created a huge table in mysql,
say

```
table1
```

i will be querying on this table for my results, continuously

once a week i will be flushing the values in table1 and insert new values.

(this process takes 3 hours of time.)

So my issue is my querying will be stopped for 3 hours(while the new table1 is being generated) ,  and my querying should be continuous.

i was thinking of creating a like table

```
create like table temp_table1 from table1
```

and till the time new table1 is getting populated, i will be using temp_table1 for querying.
But for that i also wanted to set an automated trigger for changing between tables.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

also  creating like table for a huge table would take a lot of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it other way actually...

1. create table temp_table1 same as table1
2. Do your process in temp_table1 instead of table1
3. Once process completes insert the data to main table using `insert into .. select from` construct

That way your main table is free for querying and won't be blocked. The final insert could be fast enough depending on the `select` performance.

Comment: if process means querying, and i am doing querying on temp_table1 for a week, and on the day which i update my table1 with new values, i have to update the same in temp_table1.

Comment: @SRingne, process means insert new values .. your 3hr long process

Comment: @SRingne, also consider accepting answers of your previous questions if found helpful.